# Sublime Text 3 uses a lot of CPU when typing, but about 1% in idle mode

Tags: sublimetext3, cpu-usage

When typing in Sublime Text 3 it takes several seconds to type each letter, number, sign, etc. The problem appeared today, I haven't installed any packages for Sublime Text 3 today nor have I installed anything on my computer recently. When the problem occurred for the first time I decided to check the system resources via `htop`. I saw this:

[image: laptop resources while typing in Sublime Text 3]

I spent a long time investigating the problem and discovered that everyone who had this problem stated that the reason is file indexing, and the following solutions were proposed:

1. Renaming/removing the 'Index' folder and letting Sublime Text recreate it.
2. Adding the following to Sublime's configuration file:

   ```
   {
   "folder_exclude_patterns": [
       "node_modules",
       "vendor",
       "pages-desktop"
   ],

   "index_files": false,
   }
   ```

I don't have any "Index" folders in `~/.config/sublime-text-3/`. I tried to remove the whole `~/.config/sublime-text-3/` folder but that didn't work. Also I don't have any Sublime Text 3 console outputs about indexing. "Indexing status" table is empty. I reinstalled the editor several times from the Ubuntu repository, from the official Sublime Text 3 site. I also tried to install older versions of the program.
Still I can't fix the problem.

My OS in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.